Are there books with exercises on $\pi$ and $e$?
$\pi$ and $e$ are constants which we stumble on everytime we are doing math. I wonder if there is some book which exploits this fact and contains exercises whose solution involved these constants.

Any theoretical statistics book is bound to make use of those constants. Actually any book on integration techniques will as well.

Try googling "books problems e pi".

"e: The Story of a Number" by Eli Maor

A history of $\pi$ by Peter Beckmann

So you want a book where all the exercise solutions contain pi or $e$? Why do you want such a book? Those constants arise naturally in certain contexts. What you're talking about is contrived. Which is not a bad thing, but it's a bit random and I don't see what the motivation could be.

@copper.hat I tried a similar search, but with no result.

@JeanMarie: I know of both books, but they focus on the history behind the constants (and in the case of Beckmann to bash whoever he did not like)

@AdamRubinson: I am writing a booklet about these constants (and &varphi, added for good or bad), and I would like to add some questions which lead naturally to them. For example I can use the problem of the secretary who puts letters in a random envelope, or the method allegedly chosen by Kepler to find a wife, to get (an approximation of) e; the idea is actually to show that such numbers are quite common even in problems not contrived.

About an "uprising" of $e$ in a place where it wasn't expected, see this answer to a question of mine.

Not a recommendation, but Google returns https://www.amazon.com/%CF%80-Three-fundamental-numbers-mathematics/dp/B08XL7YX9M. I don't know if this has problems: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6278#t=aboutBook

@Adam Rubinson Please give it as an answer. It is appropriate because OP has said that he/she writes a booklet of exercises about these numbers. I would be happy (as others hopefully) to learn about this new 'uprising" of $e$ and probably upvote this answer.

@JeanMarie Ok - done. I kind of already wrote the answer in the comments, but now I deleted this comment and so hopefully everyone has forgotten what I wrote, so that they can discover the answer for themselves.

As requested in the comments, here is a question I came up with, and after investigating it, realised the answer has to do with one of the mathematical constants $\pi$ or $e$ (although I will not reveal which one).

Is there $a_1\in \left( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right),$ and a sequence
$a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n-1\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ such that
$\frac{1}{n+1} < a_n < \frac{1}{n}\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}?$

When I first came up with this problem, I thought the answer was "no", and that the problem was related to the irregularity of distributions problem. However, this is not the case, and I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to discover the truth.

I have programmed your sequence with the following Matlab code : a=exp(1)-2 % your initialization)  ;A=[a];
for n=1:20
a=(n+1)*a-1
A=[A,a];
end
1./A and what I obtain is indeed a sequence  whose integer parts are 1,2,3,...15, and suddenly, this sequence behaves in a foolish way. How do you explain it ?

@JeanMarie "I obtain a sequence with integer part $1,2,3,\ldots, 15.$" I'm not sure what you mean by this. If $a_1 = e-2,$ then $a_2=0.436\ldots,\ a_3=0.309\ldots, \ a_4=0.238\ldots.$ So they all satisfy the inequality $\frac{1}{n+1} < a_n < \frac{1}{n}\ $. To prove this will always happen, consider: $a_1=e-2 = \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}.$

Explanation : instead of $\frac{1}{n+1} < a_n < \frac{1}{n}$, I am working on the inverses $n < \frac{1}{a_n} < n+1$; it is why I consider the integer part of $ \frac{1}{a_n} $

@JeanMarie you don't need to do that though. You're doing it as an aside?

In fact, the justification is based on the following "Horner scheme" : $e-2=\frac12(1+\frac13(1+\frac14(1+(\cdots))))$

[...Ctd] See in particular Engel expansion

Precalculus would be a good place to start
https://openstax.org/details/books/precalculus-2e/
Chapters 4 and 5.
